# Using bootstrap output to measure accuracy of K fold cross validation Machine Learning

Tags: r, machine-learning

I've at this question for quite a while and am unable to figure out how to use bootstraps output to measure the accuracy of a k fold cross validation, specifically when k=5. I believe I've coded both correctly (I get the output for a k=5 cross validation and a bootstrap) but I dont know how they can be linked together theory wise? I know that k fold cross validation is giving me the mean successful test predictions from my model, and my bootstrap is giving me the standard error. Im unsure how this standard error can be used in accordance to the k fold cross validation, other than potentially comparing it the standard error of the logistics model, but thats just me stretching what I know and praying.

Side note:What should index B for the bootstrap? Unsure but train has 450 obs and test has 180 :)

Code:

```
log.fit <- glm(highcrime ~ density+prbpris+prbarr+polpc, data = crime, family = "binomial")
summary(log.fit)
cost.fn <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)
cv.glm(crime,log.fit,cost=cost.fn)$delta[1]
cv.glm(crime,log.fit,cost=cost.fn, K=3)$delta[1]
cv.glm(crime,log.fit,cost=cost.fn, K=5)$delta[1]
cv.glm(crime,log.fit,cost=cost.fn, K=10)$delta[1]
cv.glm(crime,log.fit,cost=cost.fn, K=20)$delta[1]



boot.fn = function(data, index=200) {
  logit.fit <- glm(highcrime ~ density+prbpris+prbarr+polpc, data = crime, family = "binomial", subset=index)
  return (coef(logit.fit))
}
set.seed(10)
boot(Default,boot.fn,200)
```

Outputs:

```
Call:
glm(formula = highcrime ~ density + prbpris + prbarr + polpc, 
    family = "binomial", data = crime)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.15233  -0.79314  -0.01228   0.75161   2.04665  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -2.4275     0.5939  -4.088 4.36e-05 ***
density       2.1346     0.2287   9.333  < 2e-16 ***
prbpris       2.0586     1.1908   1.729 0.083849 .  
prbarr       -3.3042     0.8720  -3.789 0.000151 ***
polpc       162.4758    55.0382   2.952 0.003157 ** 



Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 873.37  on 629  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 599.10  on 625  degrees of freedom
AIC: 609.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

> cv.glm(crime,log.fit,cost=cost.fn, K=5)$delta[1]
[1] 0.2444444



Call:
boot(data = Default, statistic = boot.fn, R = 200)


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original      bias    std. error
t1*  -2.427495 -0.02408247   0.5500529
t2*   2.134586  0.01427247   0.2267037
t3*   2.058553  0.06418547   1.1090652
t4*  -3.304248 -0.17618726   0.8482598
t5* 162.475758 20.89146943  56.7783311
```